# Ubuntu server 23.10 100% CPU cannot ssh - how to diagnose?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a ubuntu 23.10 server running on an arm board. Occasionally it seems to get into a situation where it appears to run at 100% (judging by the pwm fan speed). I can ping it, but I cant ssh to it. It has a serial console, but that doesn't show any output. The only thing I can do is power cycle it.

How can I get an idea of what the server is doing when this happens?

Comment: is there any useful information in any log files after you reboot

Comment: Check your monitoring. If you don't have monitoring that's a good reason to set it up. Log in via the local console to check the status. If you only have the serial console, they usually need some key strokes before they start showing output.

Comment: Also, consider switching to a more stable LTS release.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/var/log/messages`, `dmesg`, `journalctl` maybe you can find something like OOM-killer or message showing software overconsumption of resources.

Edit for the last session with journalctl:  `journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1`

Comment: `dmesg` is useless after reboot :p

Comment: You're right @JaromandaX you can look for this with `journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1` in FreeBSD it's /var/log/dmesg.yesterday. [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181067/how-to-read-dmesg-from-previous-session-dmesg-0)